# Hiding by using a span

Tags: jquery, html

This question might seem weird, but is it technically incorrect to wrap a set of elements all in a span. That way one could hide and show the span upon request. I only ask, because then you could have much more control where you wish to hide.

```
<did> this is a blog post</div>
<h3>title</h3>
<p>blah blah  blah blah blah<p>
<p>blah blah  blah <span class="hidden">blah blah<p>
<p>blah blah  blah blah blah<p>
<p>blah blah  blah blah blah<p>
<p>blah blah  blah blah blah<p></span>
```

This has worked when I was able to hard code the HTML.  But when I try to wrap the span around certain elements it won't wrap it any further that the nearest close tag. Any ideas? Or any better ideas?

Comment: Could you post your relative html and javascript code what you are doing now?

Comment: you can wrap only `inline` elements with `span`, try using `div`

Comment: Regardless of which wrapping element you use, I would not recommend incorrectly nesting elements

Answer (score 2):

**`<span>` is an inline element and can only contain inside such other elements such as `abbr`, `strong`, or `tt`.**

You can easily do what you pretend using a `div` as the outer element.

```
<div style="display: none">
   all this info
   <span>will be hidden</span>
   <p /> from view until
   <br /> you change the div visibility
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No it is not incorrect. In fact, this technique is often used on modern websites to hide small textboxes or helper hints. Remember that span tags are *inline* instead of *block* elements, so you may want to experiment using div tags that explicitly have "display=inline-block" in the CSS.